# Unity3d - help, this code is too slow on iPhone

Tags: unity-game-engine, alpha

I am trying to make like an eraser tool (when the user drags the finger on a texture,the texture becomes transparent on that place). I tried this using the code below (i found an example online and modified it a bit), but it is too slow. I am using a brush texture to draw on the background texture.. Is there another solution to this problem? Maybe it would be quicker using some shader but I don't know how.

Thanks for any help

```
void Start()
{
   stencilUV = new Color[stencil.width * stencil.height];
   tex = (Texture2D)Instantiate(paintMaterial.mainTexture);
}

void Update () 
{
     RaycastHit hit;
    if (Input.touchCount == 0) return;
    //if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0)) return;
    if (Physics.Raycast(mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
    {
        pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;
        pixelUV.x *= tex.width;
        pixelUV.y *= tex.height;

        CreateStencil((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y, stencil);
    }
}

void CreateStencil(int x, int y, Texture2D texture)
{
    paintMaterial.mainTexture = tex;
    for (int xPix = 0; xPix<texture.width; xPix++)
    {
        for (int yPix=0;yPix<texture.height; yPix++)
        {
            stencilUV[i] = tex.GetPixel((x - texture.width / 2) + xPix,
                (y - texture.height / 2) + yPix);
            stencilUV[i].a = 0;//1-color.a;
            i++;
        }
    }
    i=0;
    tex.SetPixels(x-texture.width/2, y-texture.height/2, texture.width, texture.height, stencilUV);
    tex.Apply();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

well as you know, the `Update()` function gets called every frame. So this is the place where you should try to optimize your code. The `CreateStencil()` function seems pretty expensive to me, as you iterate over every pixel in the texture and then call `tex.GetPixel(..)` inside your for loops - this means:
when you touch the screen the app tries to run every frame this function for every pixel in your texture - definitely not the way to go.
I would try to buffer the pixel information in some other array in the `Start()` or `Awake()` function and do only the necessary parts inside `Update()`. Every expensive opertation you can leave out there is crucial for making your app run smooth on the iPhone.